# Why does adding new properties to the graph style sheet not work in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

The Developer guide for [Neo4j Browser User Interface](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/#browser-styling) says that I can run `:style`, export it, modify it and drag it back to change the style. I try changing the default border width, and adding two new properties for nodes: `text-align` and `shape`, as explained in [Graph Stylesheets](https://www.w3.org/2001/11/IsaViz/gss/gssmanual.html#styles):

```css
node {
  diameter: 50px;
  color: #A5ABB6;
  border-color: #9AA1AC;
  border-width: 10px;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: "below";
  shape: regtangle;
}
```

But only the border width changes. Why does the rest not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align` and `shape` don't seem to be properties supported by the Neo4j browser.
The [styling guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-styling/#grass) in the [browser manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-styling/) lists eight properties.
And based on this list, only the colour of the text seems to be customisable.